# How show static content and dynamic content in react native flat list at same time?

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have a view that has top banner and some text, and after that there is a list of product which uses pagination, what I want to do is use flat list, Is there a way to configure it so that in my renderItems I'll return my products and have the the  static content in same flat list?

[image: Note: I do not have any code yet but **this picture might help a bit.**]

Comment: What content is static here? The text and the banner? How would the result change if there were different products? Kindly explain your scenario in a bit more detail.

Comment: the banner and the text will be same but the products will come from network,
What I want is take everything in same Flatlist so that the when the user scroll down the banner should also scroll, I dont want banner and text to be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

If your Banner and text will always be on top of product list then you can use **ListHeaderComponent** prop of **Flatlist** to render static content(e.g. banner and text).

```
<FlatList
     ...
     ListHeaderComponent={this.renderHeader}
/>
```

Comment: My list is completely scrollable

Comment: using ListHeaderComponent your banner and text will scroll with product list. it will not get fixed on top.

Answer (score 0):

If you have fixed banner and some text before the flatlist. You can wrap the banner, text and flatlist in scrollView.This will work as you wanted.

```
    render(){
     return(
       <ScrollView>
        this.renderBanner();
        this.renderText();
        this.renderFlatList();
      </ScrollView)
    }
```